# Git only checkout certain directories

Tags: git, git-clone, git-checkout

How can I setup my git project to only clone/checkout certain directories.

In my project I have the following directories

```
/dira
/dirb
/dirc
```

In some cases I would only like to checkout `dira`, in some cases I would only like to checkout `dirb`, and in some cases I would only like to checkout `dirc`.  There are also times I would want to checkout all 3 directories.

Comment: I have looked into sparse checkout but it appears you can only setup one way of partially cloning the repository

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple but you cant configure git to do automatically:

```
# Checkout any desired file or path
git checkout <commit id> -- /path/to/dir
```

---

***Note***

The 2 `--` at the end are important and cannot be left off.

Comment: Cool, in Jenkins you can use the shell box to execute scripts.